# Can Nginx limit the request by status code?

Tags: nginx

I wanna limit the ip who has 150 nums  500 status code request last minute.

I only get the limit_req_zone module that can limit  by the ip count.

Is there any way to limit by status code?

Thanks

Comment: This could be of help: https://serverfault.com/questions/907860/nginx-limit-request-based-on-response-status-code#987321

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to limit by any `key`. See [`limit_req_zone`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone).

Example:

```
limit_req_zone "$binary_remote_addr$request_uri" zone=one:10m rate=2r/s;
```

Notice the `$binary_remote_addr$request_uri`. You can use any variable here (ip + status code in your case).

Comment: Can i only limit the status code 500? when using "ip + status code " mode , the code 200 will be limited.